# How can I output messages from FinalBuilder that will be captured by TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, finalbuilder

I'm running TeamCity Professional 4.5.3 and FinalBuilder Pro 6; TeamCity's running the FinalBuilder project using a command-line task.

How do I get FinalBuilder to print messages into the build log, so that TeamCity will capture them? The [TeamCity documentation](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) is clear enough but I can't find any way to output the required values from FinalBuilder - do I need to call `echo` as a DOS command, or run a tiny snippet of script, or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Run Script action (Javascript) :

```
Action.SendLogMessage("hello team city",stInformation);
```

Answer (score 4):

Action.SendLogMessage("Hello World!",stInformation)